# Which text editor for python development?

Tags: python, text, ide, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Which is the preferred text editor for python development, Vim, emacs or any other ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no **preferred** editor for anything. It's whatever your personal preference is. I personally prefer emacs with python-mode because it makes indenting easier (and indenting is kind of important in python), but anything will work.

Comment: I hear a LOT of discussion about indenting issues with Python.  Is this really that big of a deal?  I use Notepad++ on Win7 and have it set for tab to be 4 spaces.  I guess that's the right thing to do?

Comment: That will work fine as long as you don't need to share code with another developer using a different editor.

Comment: 4 spaces is the recommended thing to do, as defined in PEP 8. If you edit a file that someone else has written with tabs for indentation, though, adding indentation with spaces can break it.

Answer (score 0):

VIM! And not for Python only.

Answer (score 0):

The best editor is the one that works for you. Period! If you are comfortable with `gedit`, use that. If you are comfortable with `emacs`, use that. The word best is subjective, unless you are looking for specific features that vary from one to another.